# jdbcTemplate BatchUpdate sending row by row instead of bigger batch

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

Spring JdbcTemplate is sending small batch sizes of 1-3. I would like batch sizes of 10,000. The code im using to call the batchUpdate is below, and the logs im seeing on the postgres db from AWS.

I have on my jdbc connection rewriteBatchedStatements set to true. I have also tried re-writing my functions to the code in the last codespace.

My goal is to have one insert of 10,000 records, logged like this on the db.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_list)
VALUES
    (value_list_1),
    (value_list_2),
    ...
    (value_list_n);
```

```
    public void insertTest(UUID var1, int var2, List<Shape> Tests)
    {
        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
                "INSERT INTO database.table VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                Tests,
                10000,
                (ps, entity) ->
                {
                    ps.setObject(1, var1);
                    ps.setLong(2, var2);
                    ps.setObject(3, entity.getVar3());
                    ps.setObject(4, entity.getVar4());
                    ps.setObject(5, entity.getVar5());
                    ps.setObject(6, entity.getVar6());
                    ps.setObject(7, entity.getVar7());
                });
    }
```

```
2023-09-26T12:47:13.000+13:00   2023-09-25 23:47:13 UTC:10.20.0.125(28120):database:[4882]:LOG: duration: 0.003 ms bind S_1: INSERT INTO database.table VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)

2023-09-26T12:47:13.000+13:00   2023-09-25 23:47:13 UTC:10.20.0.125(28120):database:[4882]:DETAIL: parameters: $1 = 'data', $2 = '1', $3 = 'data', $4 = '1', $5 = 'data', $6 = 'data'

2023-09-26T12:47:13.000+13:00   2023-09-25 23:47:13 UTC:10.20.0.125(28120):database:[4882]:LOG: execute S_1: INSERT INTO database.table  VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
```

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchPreparedStatementSetter;

    public int[] batchInsert(List<Book> books) {

        return this.jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
            "insert into books (name, price) values(?,?)",
            new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                    ps.setString(1, books.get(i).getName());
                    ps.setBigDecimal(2, books.get(i).getPrice());
                }

                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return books.size();
                }

            });
    }
```

From this link: https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-example/

Thank you

Comment: The `rewriteBatchedStatements` is for MySQL not Postgres. You should check the database not the logging from the java client. That can log individual queries (MySQL does as well) but the actual SQL send to to database is a batched insert.

Comment: It looks like its for postgres aswell, https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/#:~:text=reWriteBatchedInserts

Those queries are from the RDS not from the java client